# Javascript spread all value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object contains value is array, like:

```js
const CHANNELS = {
    FACEBOOK: [{
            value: 'face1',
            label: 'Facebook Account'
        },{
            value: 'face1',
            label: 'Facebook Group'
        },
    ],
    LINKEDIN: [{
            value: '',
            label: 'All'
        }, {
            value: 'english',
            label: 'English'
        }, {
            value: 'korean',
            label: 'Korean'
        }
    ],
    YOUTUBE: [{
            value: 'youtube1',
            label: 'Youtube channel'
        }, {
            value: 'youtube2',
            label: 'Youtube'
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to get all value from key in this array.
So, my expect array as output like:

```js
const array = [{
            value: 'face1',
            label: 'Facebook Account'
        }, {
            value: 'face1',
            label: 'Facebook Group'
        }, {
            value: '',
            label: 'All'
        }, {
            value: 'english',
            label: 'English'
        }, {
            value: 'korean',
            label: 'Korean'
        }, {
            value: 'youtube1',
            label: 'Youtube channel'
        }, {
            value: 'youtube2',
            label: 'Youtube'
        }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Btw; I've removed your "code inline link online" link since it was just a link to the Stackoverflow home page ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the value of the objects with `Object.values()`

Then use `flat()` to flatten it into a single array

```js
const CHANNELS = {
    FACEBOOK: [{value: 'face1', label: 'Facebook Account'},{value: 'face1', label: 'Facebook Group'}, ],
    LINKEDIN: [{value: '', label: 'All'}, {value: 'english', label: 'English'}, {value: 'korean', label: 'Korean'} ],
    YOUTUBE: [{value: 'youtube1', label: 'Youtube channel'}, {value: 'youtube2', label: 'Youtube'} ]
};

const res = Object.values(CHANNELS).flat();
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```js
let arr = [];

for (const key in CHANNELS) {
  for (const iterator of CHANNELS[key]) {
    arr.push(iterator);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const CHANNELS = {
    FACEBOOK: [{
            value: 'face1',
            label: 'Facebook Account'
        },{
            value: 'face1',
            label: 'Facebook Group'
        },
    ],
    LINKEDIN: [{
            value: '',
            label: 'All'
        }, {
            value: 'english',
            label: 'English'
        }, {
            value: 'korean',
            label: 'Korean'
        }
    ],
    YOUTUBE: [{
            value: 'youtube1',
            label: 'Youtube channel'
        }, {
            value: 'youtube2',
            label: 'Youtube'
        }
    ]
};

let a = []
let brand = ["FACEBOOK","LINKEDIN","YOUTUBE"]

for (j=0;j<brand.length;j++){
  for (var i = 0; i < CHANNELS[brand[j]].length; i++) {
    }
       a.push(CHANNELS[brand[j]])
        
}  
console.log(a)
```